# MS Visio 2007: How do I get the cardinality to appear on both ends of a relationship?

Tags: visio, cardinality

In Visio 2007, I can only seem to set the cardinality of the Parent-to-child relationship, but I want to set the Child-to-Parent as well. Is there a reason Visio won't let me do this? Do I need to create a separate relationship to achieve this? I'm using two Entity objects/shapes and a Relationship object/shape.

Note: I got the cardinality to appear on the diagram by going Database > Options >> Document and checking the Cardinality box.

Comment: Wouldn't the child:parent cardinality just be the inverse of the parent:child?

Comment: I'm not sure if parent/child is the correct term, but it's what Visio uses. 1 table A could have a 1 to * (many) relationship with another table B, but Table B could have a 0 to 1 relationship with the table A. For example, a program at college could have 1 to many students, but a student may have 0 or 1 program.

Comment: Okay I understand, it's just the way Visio works and how DBs work. A foreign key in one table does not mean there has to be a foreign key in another table. It's been a while since I've done DBs. ^_^""

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Menu; 
Database > Options >> Document

Click Relationship Tab. You will see Name Display. Check "show verb phase". Choose "Foward text", "Inverse text" or both.. That depands on your wish.

Answer (score 1):

Visio uses multiplicity/cardinality on both sides when completing a UML Model Diagram; double-clicking the connector will allow you to select the multiplicity/cardinality from the drop-down options for both directions. Using the Entity setup will just give you a check box that is relatively useless for what you want to do.